# Why is Rails test output missing critical information when using Ruby 1.9.3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I recently upgraded from 1.9.2 to 1.9.3 and noticed that test output (Test::Unit) is missing some items, specifically the words "FAIL" and "ERROR", and the assertion message. Any idea what's wrong?

Here's a screen shot:

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by changing

```
gem 'turn', '0.8.2', :require => false
```

to

```
gem 'turn', :require => false
```